# How to sort an array of objects by one of the objects string values numerically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects similar to this :

```
 var this array = [
    { 
    "id" : "A20",
    "age" : "16"
    },
    {
    "id" : "A2",
    "age" : "12"
    },
    { 
    "id" : "B16",
    "age" : "45"
    }]
```

I need to sort this array by their ID, So it would end up like :

```
this array = [
        { 
        "id" : "A2",
        "age" : "12"
        },
        {
        "id" : "A20",
        "age" : "16"
        },
        { 
        "id" : "B16",
        "age" : "45"
        }]
```

I have this method of sorting :

```
nodes.sort(function(a,b){
    // console.log(a.Pos)
    // console.log(a.pinNum)
    var alc = a.id, blc = b.id;
    console.log(alc)
    return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
    });
```

But this only works alphabetically. I have also found this but it gives back just the strings I pass to the function not the array of objects :

```
function sortArray(arr) {
        var tempArr = [],
        n;
        console.log(arr)
        for (var i in arr) {

            var thisString = arr[i].id;

            // tempArr[i] = arr[i].match(/([^0-9]+)|([0-9]+)/g);
            tempArr[i] = thisString.match(/([^0-9]+)|([0-9]+)/g);
            for (var j in tempArr[i]) {
                if (!isNaN(n = parseInt(tempArr[i][j]))) {
                    tempArr[i][j] = n;
                }
            }
        }
        tempArr.sort(function (x, y) {
            for (var i in x) {
                if (y.length < i || x[i] < y[i]) {
                    return -1; // x is longer
                }
                if (x[i] > y[i]) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });
        for (var i in tempArr) {
            arr[i] = tempArr[i].join('');
        }
        return arr;
    }
    console.log(sortArray(nodes).join(","));
```

What I need is the second sorting function but with the ability to sort both alphabetically and numerically. Thanks

Comment: `var alc = +a.id, blc = +b.id;`

Comment: @dandavis could you explain more on your point please ?

Comment: @dandavis but my string is made up of both letters and numbers ? "A20" ...

Comment: ooooooops, i should read it closer, sorry.

Comment: Tell us more about the rule of compare, is it simply remove any prefix non-digits? or there's some other rules?

Comment: if you chop the letter off and pad the digits with leading zeros above code will work.

Comment: yes but in my data set i have the following id's : A1,A2,A3...A20,A30,B1,B20,B30 ... and a lot more, so i need to keep the letters, otherwise it wont sort properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array = [{ 
   "id" : "A20",
   "age" : "16"
}, {
   "id" : "A2",
   "age" : "12"
}, { 
   "id" : "B16",
   "age" : "45"
}];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
 var aSplit = /(\D*)(\d*)/.exec(a.id),
     bSplit = /(\D*)(\d*)/.exec(b.id);

 if( aSplit[1] !== bSplit[1] )
    return aSplit[1].localeCompare(bSplit[1]);
 else
    return aSplit[2] - bSplit[2];
});
```

Comment: nice answer but it doesn't work. If i have these as id's : 'A1','A20','A11','A'2. The output after sorting is : 'A1','A11','A2','A20'

Comment: error, if you change id 'A2', for 'A120', you receive a wrong order

Comment: You'll have to split then, compare the letters then the digits.

Comment: i thought as much :( Thanks for the input. Ill try do the split and answer the question, if you manage to solve it ill chose yours as the correct answer :)

Comment: it's "localeCompare" (with an 'e'), but it won't help with the mixed letter and number problem here...

Comment: @dandavis I updated it, it isn't just using `localeCompare`.

Comment: that works perfectly. I made a mistake in my question. The ID's are like this : J2A10,J2A1,P2B34,P2A12... and so on. I think ill have to split to solve in that case but you have solved what i asked, thank you, i shall chose yours as the correct one :)

Comment: would you be able to explain the 'aSplit' line, the /(\D*)(\d*)/.exec(a.id), Not sure whats happening there

Comment: @thisOneGuy It's executing a RegEx, here's a site that explains well what's going on, you can read on the panel on the right upper corner. https://regex101.com/r/kQ8rB6/1

Comment: @thisOneGuy if you do the `.exec` on a while you can extract all the bits of the string, and you can store them in an array, one array for `a.id` and one for `b.id`, then compare each index of this array, while they're equal go to the next index, if they're non equal, return the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use function .sort in array, and pass has argument, a callback.

This callback receive elements to iterate, and you can compare values, if return true, switch order of elements, for i.e:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.age) > parseInt(b.age))
};
```

or, if you use ecma script 6, you can use arrow function, is better, i.e. below:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.age) > parseInt(b.age))
```

Docs here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: it's not the age i want to sort, its the ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use localeCompare() to compare strings. Try this code, it should work:

```
nodes.sort(function(a,b){
    // console.log(a.Pos)
    // console.log(a.pinNum)
    var alc = a.id, blc = b.id;
    console.log(alc)
    return alc.localeCompare(blc);
});
```